# Querying in all Firebase database about a specific key and get it's children value Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in Firebase and Android. My problem to search about specific key and check whether it exists or not. When it exists, I take the URL value of that key and show it to the user.
All of that should happen without any changes in the database.

So what should I do? Thanks.

Here's my database structure:

```
{
  "images" : {
    "partner " : {
      "text" : "partner",
      "url" : "http://res.cloudinary.com/dg3jylcsw/image/upload/v1483565650/sister_x3lv6j.png"
    },
    "sister" : {
      "text " : "sister",
      "url" : "http://res.cloudinary.com/dg3jylcsw/image/upload/v1483565650/sister_x3lv6j.png"
    }
  }
}
```

my code:

```
package com.example.android.testy;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.Query;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                String string = input.getText().toString();
                Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://test-219f8.firebaseio.com/images");
                Query queryRef = rootRef.orderByKey().equalTo(String.valueOf(input));
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you searching for an exact value in a particular location, or a general text search of the whole database? What have you tried so far? Please include any relevant code you have and the data as plain text instead of an image.

Comment: i'm sorry i'll update my question to be clear, and i didn't attach any code because i don't know what to do after the reference of my database .
yes i want to search about exact key for example sister when i found it i should take the url value and show it to the user i hope that be clear

Comment: It'll help to include all the relevant code, sample data, debug logging, and version info so we can fully understand the problem. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i hope now it's clear enough :D

Comment: Use GSon to de-serialize JSON string into your model and then you can check if it is null/empty or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainactivity:

```
package com.example.android.testy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://test-219f8.firebaseio.com/images");
        Query queryRef = rootRef.orderByKey().equalTo("sister");
        queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                test data = dataSnapshot.getValue(test.class);

                System.out.println(data.getUrl());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


}
```

that test class include what we want to retrieve from  the specific key children

test class:

```
package com.example.android.testy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class test {
    private String text;
    private String url;

    public test() {
        // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```